# how to get the starting simulation time from gazebo?

Tags: ros, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear,
I have a controller for a simple robot in gazebo. In my controller, I need to get the starting simulated time because there is lag between starting gazebo simulation and starting my controller. In my controller, I used this line (Init_time) to get the starting simulation time, but it always got out 0.

Init_time = ros::Time::now().toSec();

double time = odom->header.stamp.toSec();

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12618/how-to-get-the-starting-simulation-time-from-gazebo-?/) by [maruchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1429/maruchi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2012-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you use sim time, the time starts at zero. That's not an error, that's just where time begins when you launch Gazebo. If you do a `rostopic echo /clock`, you will see that it's close to zero.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-01-13**:
If you do `rostopic echo /clock`, does it show a simulated time properly? Also, try running your node without gazebo and use_sim_time and see if it works then.

**Comment by [maruchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1429/maruchi/) on 2012-01-13**:
Yes, I set "use_sim_time" parameter  true

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-01-13**:
Do you have the "use_sim_time" parameter set to true?

**Comment by [maruchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1429/maruchi/) on 2012-01-12**:
I start them in two separate terminals. Do you think I have to start them in the same launch file ? If I start them in the same launch file, how can I put my cpp file in the lauch file? Could you guide me a tutorial ?

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-01-12**:
Do you start them in the same launch file or in two separate terminals?

**Comment by [maruchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1429/maruchi/) on 2012-01-12**:
I start gazebo simulation first and then load my controller. When the gazebo simulation start, 'Sim Time' has passed by. When I start my controller, I want to use the 'Sim Time' when my controller loaded. What should I edit in my controller which is written as C++ ?